# How to fix these error in this code palindrome problem to tell whether it is odd or even

Tags: c

A given string is palindrome, you need to state that it is even palindrome (palindrome with even length) or odd palindrome (palindrome with odd length) otherwise return No.

This code i write but not get true output

```
#include<string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n ;
    char s[100000],b[100000];
    int count=0,d,h,i,t,j;

    if(count<1)
    {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if(n<=50)
        {
            for(t=1;t<=n;t++)
            {
                i=0,j=0,h=0;

                scanf("%s", s);

                h=strlen(s)-1;
                if(h>=1&&h<=100000)
                {
                    for(i=0,j=h;i<=h&&j>=0; j--,i++)
                    {
                        b[i]=s[j];

                    } 

                    if(strcmp(s,b)==0)
                    {
                        if(h%2==0)
                        {
                            printf("YES EVEN");
                            printf("\n");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("YES ODD");
                            printf("\n");
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        printf("NO");
                        printf("\n");
                    }
                }
            }       
        }
        count++;
    }
    return 0;
}
#include<string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n ;
    char s[100000],b[100000];
    int count=0,d,h,i,t,j;

    if(count<1)
    {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if(n<=50)
        {
            for(t=1;t<=n;t++)
            {
                i=0,j=0,h=0;

                scanf("%s", s);

                h=strlen(s)-1;
                if(h>=1&&h<=100000)
                {
                    for(i=0,j=h;i<=h&&j>=0; j--,i++)
                    {
                        b[i]=s[j];

                    } 

                    if(strcmp(s,b)==0)
                    {
                        if(h%2==0)
                        {
                            printf("YES EVEN");
                            printf("\n");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("YES ODD");
                            printf("\n");
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        printf("NO");
                        printf("\n");
                    }
                }
            }       
        }
        count++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Forget about syntax error only find logical error.

I expect the output is

Input

```
3
abc
abba
aba
```

Your Code's Output

```
NO
YESODD
NO
```

Expected Correct Output

```
NO
YESEVEN
YESODD
```

I get true result when i provide one string not more than that 
but where is error.

Comment: Fix your code formatting /. indentation.

Comment: Single-letter var names.....skip to next question:(

Answer (score 0):

1. When creating the string `b` you forget to add the terminating character `\0`
2. While checking for even you use `h%2`. But `h` is `strlen(s)-1`. So you need to set odd if `h%2 == 0`

Relevant changes are shown below

```
for(i=0,j=h;i<=h&&j>=0; j--,i++)
{
    b[i]=s[j];

} 
b[h+1] = '\0';

if(strcmp(s,b)==0)
{
    if(h%2!=0)
    {
        printf("YES EVEN");
        printf("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("YES ODD");
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

> Forget about syntax error only find logical error.

I find this sort of statement very wrong. Unless you fix the syntax, you cannot look at it logically. Also proper indentation really helps in debugging the code and finding errors on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of problems, but your primary problem is in your reversal. You attempt to reverse with:

```
    h=strlen(s)-1;
    if(h>=1&&h<=100000){
     for(i=0,j=h;i<=h&&j>=0; j--,i++) {
        b[i]=s[j];
    }
```

This will fail for `strlen(s) == 1`, does not ensure nul-termination and because you use `h=strlen(s)-1;`, your `h` in `if (h % 2 == 0)` results in the **opposite** determination of `EVEN` and `ODD`. Instead you need:

```
#define MAXC 100000     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
...
    h = strlen (s);             /* h must be strlen(s) - not - 1 */
    if (h >= 1 && h < MAXC) {   /* now loop j=h-1; j < h  times */
        for (i = 0, j = h-1; i < h && j >= 0; j--,i++)
            b[i] = s[j];
        b[i] = 0;               /* and ensure b is nul-terminated */
```

(**note:** adequately spaced code is much easier to read and debug)

Next, you fail to validate the return of every call to `scanf`, instead, blindly using the variables without any indication of whether your input succeeded -- a recipe for *Undefined Behavior*. You must validate EVERY user input, e.g.

```
    if (scanf ("%d", &n) != 1 || n > 50) {
        fputs ("error: invalid integer or out-of-range.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    while (n-- && scanf ("%s", s) == 1) {
```

Simply choosing a logical factoring of your code eliminates the need altogether for variables `t` and `d`. Note, your conditions on `n` are (1) it's valid, and (2) it's `50` or less. Those can be combined into a single check. The same goes for looping `n` times while reading words into `s`.

Making those changes, your code simplifies to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 100000     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void)
{
    char s[MAXC];
    int n;

    if (scanf ("%d", &n) != 1 || n > 50) {
        fputs ("error: invalid integer or out-of-range.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    while (n-- && scanf ("%s", s) == 1) {
        char b[MAXC];               /* b is only needed within loop */
        int h = strlen (s), i = 0, j;   /* as are h, i, j, no - 1 for h */
        if (h >= 1 && h < MAXC) {   /* now loop j=h-1; j < h  times */
            for (i = 0, j = h-1; i < h && j >= 0; j--,i++)
                b[i] = s[j];
            b[i] = 0;               /* and ensure b is nul-terminated */

            if (strcmp (s, b) == 0) {
                if (h % 2 == 0)
                    printf ("YES EVEN\n");
                else
                    printf ("YES ODD\n");
            }
            else
                printf ("NO\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which now provides the palindrome check and `ODD` or `EVEN` length output you were looking for, e.g.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "5 abcba abccba abcdba a aa" | ./bin/pdromerefmt
YES ODD
YES EVEN
NO
YES ODD
YES EVEN
```

You should further protect the array bounds of `s` by including the *field-width* modifier for the `"%s"` conversion, e.g. `"%99999s"` which eliminates the need to check `h <= 100000` (which would have already invoked *Undefined Behavior* if input was `100000` characters or greater). There is no need to check `h >= 1` as the loop limits do nothing with `h = 0` -- but do ensure an empty-string.

With the further tweaks and array bounds protections, your loop simplifies to:

```
    while (n-- && scanf ("%99999s", s) == 1) {
        char b[MAXC];                   /* b is only needed within loop */
        int h = strlen(s), i = 0, j = h;/* as are h, i, j, no -1 for h */
        while (j--)             /* must loop j times, regardless */
            b[i++] = s[j];      /* reversing characters in s in b */
        b[i] = 0;               /* and ensure b is nul-terminated */

        if (strcmp (s, b) == 0) {
            if (h % 2 == 0)
                printf ("YES EVEN\n");
            else
                printf ("YES ODD\n");
        }
        else
            printf ("NO\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Forget about syntax error only find logical error.

That's what pencils and papers (or your rubber duck, maybe) are for, to figure out an algorithm and logically follow its steps. You have a complete program, though, and a large number of tests to try it. Now it's time to eradicate every single bug you can find, *starting* from syntax errors, which are "easily" detectable at compile time.

There are already enough answers about the flaws in the posted code, but there is at least one thing not yet covered, which isn't really a bug or a logic mistake, though.

The posted algorithm, for every test case, does the following:

- Read a word (with `scanf`).
- Find it size (with `strlen`).
- Create a reversed copy of it (using a `for` loop).
- Compare the copy with the original to check the palindromicity (with `strcmp`).

Why all those copies and array traversals? Once you know the length of the word you can just compare the left side of the string with the right side.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MAX_CHARS_IN_STR  100000
#define MAX_N_TESTS           50

// Performs the check without copying the the string
// length: size of the word
bool is_palindrome(size_t length, const char *str);

#define STRINGIFY_IMPL(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY_IMPL(x)
#define STR_WIDTH_FMT(x) "%" STRINGIFY(x) "s"

int main(void)
{
    int n_words;
    if ( scanf("%d", &n_words) != 1  ||  n_words < 1  ||  n_words > MAX_N_TESTS)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: the input is not a valid integer between 1 and %d.",
                MAX_N_TESTS);
        return 1;
    }

    int n_chars;
    // Allocates an array big enough (including the null-terminator)
    char word[MAX_CHARS_IN_STR + 1];
    // It will use an array of two pointers instead of another if-else
    const char *even_or_odd_str[] = { "IS EVEN", "IS ODD" };
    while ( n_words-- )
    {
        // consume whitespace characters left in the input
        scanf(" ");

        // reads the string up to its maximum width or until the first whitespace.
        // The macro expands to "%100000s" and that literal will be concatenated to "%n",
        // which returns the number of characters read.
        if ( scanf(STR_WIDTH_FMT(MAX_CHARS_IN_STR) "%n", word, &n_chars) != 1 )
        {
            fputs("Error: unable to read word.", stderr);
            break;
        }

        if ( is_palindrome(n_chars, word) )
            puts(even_or_odd_str[n_chars % 2]);
        else
            puts("NO");
    }
}

bool is_palindrome(size_t n, const char *str)
{
    assert(n && str);
    size_t i = 0, j = n - 1;
    while ( i < j  &&  str[i] == str[j] )
    {
        ++i;
        --j;
    }
    // It's a palindrome only if the two indices met halfway
    return i >= j;
}
```